# elFinder on Windows Xampp, not view files with non utf-8 characters

Tags: utf-8, elfinder

I have installed elFinder explorer in Windows XAMPP, but all files and directories that use `ñ`, `Ñ`, and accented characters (Spanish) aren't listed.

The problem is that the Windows volume uses an ISO file system, and elFinder uses UTF-8.

**Is there are any way to configure elFinder for to work in ISO mode?**

I tried to change configuration options with encoding and locale parameters, but without any effect.

Comment: Solved installing xampp 7.2, destects and run correctly different file system codifications

Comment: Yes, It work correctly on PHP 7.1 or later.